# Angular directive not triggered on dynamic element

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive (DirectiveA), which makes an $http call and creates a new html code.

**directiveA**

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').directive('directiveA', directiveA);
})();
(function(){
    angular.module('app').controller('DirectiveAController', DirectiveAController);
})();

function directiveA($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            url:'@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="template" ng-bind-html="template"></div>',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
         scope.element = element;
        },
        controller: DirectiveAController
    };
}

directiveA.$inject = ['$timeout']

function DirectiveAController($scope, $http, $sce){
        $http.get(`${$scope.url}`).then(function(res){
            if(res.success){
                $scope.template = $sce.trustAsHtml(res.template);
            }
        });
}
DirectiveAController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http','$sce'];
```

this works fine.

On the new created element, i want to capture the click function using another directive.

**Directive 2**

```
(function(){
    angular.module('mcq').directive('captureClick', captureClick);
})();

function captureClick($timeout, $compile){
    return {
       
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log("i am called") // Working on page load but not on dynamic element
            
         scope.element = element;
        },

    };
}

captureClick.$inject = ['$timeout', '$compile'];
```

**response.template**

```
<button capture-click></button>
```

Rendered a dummy element of response.template (as static content) and the directive works. How can i get it work on dynamically rendered element.

Answer (score 0):

Using compile my directive is picked up.

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').directive('directiveA', directiveA);
})();
(function(){
    angular.module('app').controller('DirectiveAController', DirectiveAController);
})();

function directiveA($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            url:'@'
        },
        template: '',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
         scope.element = element;
        },
        controller: DirectiveAController
    };
}

directiveA.$inject = ['$timeout']

function DirectiveAController($scope, $http, $sce, $compile){
        $http.get(`${$scope.url}`).then(function(res){
            if(res.success){
                var com = $compile(res.template)($scope);
                $scope.element.append(com[0].outerHTML);
            }
        });
}
DirectiveAController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http','$sce', '$compile'];
```

Note sure, this is the correct way and has any cons